# Cannot execute semanage fcontext --add under Fedora 21 using policy targeted

Tags: fedora, selinux

I cannot add a file contexts to the running SELinux policy using `semanage` under Fedora 21. When executing the `semanage fcontext --add` command, I receive an `OSError`:

```
mf@vienna ~ % sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/lib/owncloud(/.*)?"
libsemanage.dbase_llist_query: could not query record value (No such file or directory).
OSError: No such file or directory
```

There are no additional log entries generated (no syslog nor audit logs).

I am using the `targeted` policy in version 3.13.1-105.9.

I thought about the possibility that the `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` type was renamed/removed in that policy, but I can set that type using `chcon` and also there exist already fcontexts using that type in the running policy (`sudo semanage fcontext -l | grep httpd_sys_rw_content_t | wc -l` returns 33).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an selinux expert (by any stretch of the imagination) but I had a very similar issue to yours. I needed `/var/www` to be writeable to the httpd process in order for my scripts to work. Running:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www(/.*)?'
```

Resulted in this error:

```
libsemanage.dbase_llist_query: could not query record value (No such file or directory).
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

To fix I ended up editing the `/var/www(/.*)?` entry in `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files` then running `restorecon`.